# Gianfar Linux Kernel Driver Maximum Receive/Transmit Size

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ethernet

I have been trying to understand the code for the gianfar linux ethernet driver and was having difficulty understanding fragemented pages. I understand the maximum transmission size is 9600 bytes, however does this include fragments ?

Is it possible to send and received transmissions that are larger in size (e.g. 14000 bytes) if they are split among multiple fragements ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: By maximimum transmission size, do you mean MTU? Isn't that usually limited to 1500 bytes?

Comment: Kind of yes. The MTU is 9600, however some drivers allow you to send fragment messages. Therefore even if the MTU is 9600, you can send 3 x 4k messages. Where the skb will be composed of 3 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`9600` is a [jumbo frame maximum size](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/freescale/gianfar.h#L111). The [maximum MTU](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/freescale/gianfar.c#L1345) ("jumbo MTU") size is `9600 - 14 = 9586` bytes. Also, if I recall correctly, MTU never includes 4-byte FCS.

So, `9586` must be simply the maximum Ethernet "payload" size which can be put on wire. It's a limitation with respect to a *single* Ethernet frame. So, if you have a larger *chunk* of data ("transmission"), you might be able to "slice" it and produce multiple Ethernet frames from it (to be precise, multiple independent `skb`-s), each fitting the MTU size. So, in this case you will have *multiple* independent Ethernet frames to be handed over to the network driver. The interconnection between these frames will only be detectable on the IP header level, i.e., if you peek at IP header of the 1st frame you will be able to see "more fragments" flag indicating that the next frame contains an IP packet which is the next fragment of the original (large) *chunk* of data. But from the driver's point of view such frames should remain independent.

However, if you mean "`skb` fragments" rather than "IP fragments", then putting a 14000 byte frame into multiple fragments ("data fragments") of a single `skb` might not be helpful with respect to the MTU (say, you've configured the jumbo MTU on the interface). Because these fragments are just smaller chunks of contiguous memory containing different parts of *the same* Ethernet frame. And the driver just [makes](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/freescale/gianfar.c#L2467) *multiple* descriptors pointing to these chunks of memory. The hardware will pick them to send a *single* frame. And if the HW sees that the overall frame length is bigger than the maximum MTU, it *might* decline the transmission. Exact behaviour in this case is a topic for a separate talk.